# What's the `dynamips`, `iol` and `qemu`?

Tags: qemu

In my a virtual appliance, under the path, there are `dynamips`, `iol`, and `qemu`:

[image]

I want to know what's them, and the difference between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These all seem to be connected to emulating some operating systems and networks.

Some of them may be used in conjunctions with
[**GNS3**](https://www.gns3.com/) -
Graphical Network Simulator-3 (shortened to GNS3) is a network software emulator first released in 2008. It allows the combination of virtual and real devices, used to simulate complex networks. It uses Dynamips emulation software to simulate Cisco IOS.

**QEMU** is a generic and open source machine emulator and virtualizer.

**Dynamips** is the technology leveraged by GNS3 since inception and emulates Cisco routers and basic switching using the Etherswitch module. It emulates older Cisco hardware such as 3725 routers and uses actual Cisco IOS images.

**IOL** is IOS on Linux (IOL) aka IOS on Unix (IOU).

References :

- [GNS3](https://www.gns3.com/)
- [Which emulator should I use?](https://docs.gns3.com/1o4IX8nXISl5gb4BwoSFrUht3MeTjkzHM1TCeWAe669g/index.html)
- [Install and configure GNS3 on Arch Linux](http://binarynature.blogspot.com/2015/11/install-configure-gns3-arch-linux.html)
- [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/)